# Listing all the smart contracts deployed on ethereum

Tags: contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-debugging, nethereum

I want to list all smart contracts deployed on a private Ethereum chain, using Nethereum, and also those which were deployed by a certain address.

I have seen [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49066/how-to-get-all-the-contracts-deployed-by-a-specific-ethereum-address) and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6672/how-to-list-all-the-contracts-currently-on-the-blockchain) but I cannot get anywhere

In the second link, an answer says

> For the present time (block ~ 5250000) there are ~2350000 contracts in ethereum blockchain. My search program worked for about a week.

Aren't contracts easily identifiable on a blockchain? and if not, is it possible to create some sort of off-chain reference in a database to re-identify them quickly or something?

I am looking for practical information on how to do this on a private blockchain

Comment: It is not a duplicate, I even mentioned that link in my question and it is because it does not give me what I am looking for that I am writing a question here. I even asked a question about it.

Comment: The second answer in that link has the answer you are looking for, contract are not easily identifiable on the blockchain, you have to iterate for every block and transaction to determine if a contract was deployed. Also an 'internal transaction' can be used to deploy a contract.